# Python cerberus – choices of strings

Tags: python, cerberus

How can I validate a schema for a list of string choices?

Say I want the following animal strings to be valid:

```
['dog', 'cat', 'lion']
```

What would the schema look like for checking whether the key of `animal` contains any of these?

I can't quite figure out how to use the anyOf rule in this context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using regex?

```
schema = {'foo': {'regex': r'(ham|spam)'}} 
document = {'foo': 'ham'}
v = Validator(schema) 
v.validate(document)  # returns True
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the [allowed](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#allowed) rule is preferable as it communicates the purpose:

```py
schema = {"animal": {"allowed": ["cat", "dog", "lion"]}}
```